# Git: Managing Branches

Tags: git, merge, workflow, branch

I want to "sync" a remote branch up with head, so that when I finally merge it, it won't be a headache.  Thus, I want to try pulling head changes into my branch to see how different it is.

How can I accomplish the following workflow in Git?

1. checkout a remote branch.
2. Once I check it out, pull changes from head into it.
3. edit the branch some
4. push the branch, which now is pretty similar to HEAD, back to the remote version of the same branch (without affecting head).

Any tips on a better workflow that accomplishes the same thing would be very useful.

Answer (score 4):

This is all pretty basic stuff:

```
# make sure your notion of the remote is up to date
git fetch origin
# create and check out a branch, at the same place as the remote master branch
git checkout -b origin-master origin/master
# merge your local master
git merge master
# test, edit away, hack hack hack
git add ...
git commit ...
# push back to origin
git push origin origin-master:master
```

Terminology notes:

- Pulling is a combination of fetching and merging. When you're operating with local branches, there's no need to fetch, so you're merging, not pulling.
- HEAD doesn't mean what you think it means. (Maybe you're a cvs/svn person.) HEAD is simply the currently checked-out commit (usually referred to via a branch name). So you're not merging HEAD, you're merging that branch. I called it master here.

As for your question about better workflows to do the same thing... well, that's pretty hard to answer. Your goals are a little ambiguous. You said "slowly" sync up and refer to "finally merging it", but the steps you outline do it all at once, so... well, it's all merged. There's nothing to do later. If you wanted to do it incrementally, you could simply repeat the steps I gave, picking intermediate commits in the history to merge each time. It's also a little unclear which direction you want the merging in. Maybe you actually wanted to start from *your* branch, and merge remote stuff into it?

```
 git checkout -b master-merging master
 git fetch origin
 git merge origin/master
 # test, hack, commit, push...
 git push origin master-merging:master
```

Or with incremental merges:

```
 git checkout -b master-merging master
 git fetch origin
 git merge origin/master~20    # 20 commits before origin/master
 # test, hack, commit
 git merge origin/master~10    # 10 commits before origin/master
 # test, hack, commit
 git merge origin/master
 # test, hack, commit, push...
```

Comment: Hmm. This is very useful but Im not sure where the "branch" is?  It seems like everything your doing is in the master ?

Comment: The `git checkout -b` line, as mentioned in the comment above, creates a branch. I named it `origin-master`, to indicate that it represents origin's master branch.

Comment: Normally my branches are named something like "new-gui-experiment" .  Why are you nameing a branch using such generic terms ?

Comment: Because I have **no idea** what your branches are called, and all repositories tend to have a master branch, so I went with the lowest common denominator, and assumed that you were trying to reconcile your local master branch with the remote one. Generic answer for a generic question. (And the simplest way to denote a branch copied from a remote is surely `[remote-name]-[branch-name]`, yes?)

Comment: yes i see.  i guess im confused about wether the terms "origin" and "master" are related to any defaults or conventions in git, due to the genericity.

Comment: how do I know that I indeed have a "local master" ?  I never created such a thing.  Does it exist by default ?

Comment: The remote you cloned from is known as origin. When you run `git init`, the single branch it creates is master. So the first time any repo is created, it gets one. When you clone a repo, you get the currently-checked-out branch from it, which if no one has messed with anything, is master. You probably have one and have been ignoring it, creating branches from HEAD (which is just whatever branch you already have checked out), and have left your master branch behind? And origin's master... well, I don't know what you and the other developers are doing.

Comment: These questions are diverging from your actual question. They're also all extremely basic, and can be answered by reading or tutorials/references, e.g. http://book.git-scm.com/ or http://progit.org/book/ If you have further questions, please try reading up, or looking at other questions here. If that doesn't suffice, you're welcome to post new questions.